# How to stop &amp being store in my table

Tags: php, html

I have a web site address stored in a php variable. when i echo out the variable it shows correctly but when i use PDO to store it in a database all of the & symbols are converted to &amp which stops the link being valid.

is there anyway to store a link in a table without having & replaced with &amp?

I am using simplePie to capture from an rss feed

```
$link=$item->get_permalink();

$db->beginTransaction();

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_google_site_list (example_article) VALUES (:example_article)");
    $stmt2->bindParam(':example_article', $fulllink);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $db->commit();
```

Comment: If you inspect the output, is it still displayed as `&`? Likely you're using a function like `htmlspecialchars()` on it somewhere. You'll need to show us how you set the variable and how you insert it if you want further assistance.

Comment: I am using simplePie to capture from an rss feed    $link=$item->get_permalink();

Comment: Pdo doesn't convert anything.